# Is it possible in one line to get a class value from a function and modify it?

Tags: matlab, static, return-value, pass-by-value

If I have a class

```
classdef foo
    properties
        a = 0;
    end

    methods
        function obj foo(obj)
            obj.a = 5;
        end
    end
end
```

And a function

```
function result = GetFoo()
    result = foo();
end
```

At the command interpreter:

```
>> x = GetFoo()

x =

  foo

  Properties:
                       a: 5

  Methods

>> x.a = 10

x =

  foo

  Properties:
                       a: 10

  Methods
```

this yields an instance of foo and the value 'a' can be assigned. However, doing the same in one step:

```
>> GetFoo().a = 10

GetFoo =

  a: [1x1 struct]
```

This creates a new structure called GetFoo that overrides the class and gives it a member called 'a'. Rather than the code getting the result of GetFoo() (the class instance) and settings its property 'a' = 10, it does this instead. I can see that it is likely a hangover from the ability to create weakly typed structures on the fly and the code having to be backward compatible It also seems to be related to the fact that MATLAB has no concept of a pointer so every input/output argument is a deep copy and that the above even if it would work would be setting the value of a copy of the value GetFoo() is using to source its return object, then throwing it away.

Nonetheless the goal really is to be able to do all the work I need without creating and requiring to clear temporary variables. The intent is code maintainability as much as cosmetic style.

Comment: Some comments: 1) There *is* something remotely looking like pointers: `handle` classes, i.e. classes that inherit `handle` abstract class. These are created once and passed around as references, until nothing else refer them (then they're destroyed). However, this does not help with the behavior that you mentioned. 2) The best way to keep your Global Workspace clean is to work as much as possible with functions. Their Local Workspace is automatically cleaned up.

Comment: 3) I think is possible to do what you want in one line, but is far uglier than doing it in 2 steps. I'll try to post this abomination as an answer, but please don't downvote it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing together quite a few different issues/complaints in your question, but I suspect what you're looking for is a `handle` class. Inherit your class from `handle` (i.e. write `classdef foo < handle`, and your class will have what is basically pass-by-reference behavior. You're right that MATLAB doesn't use pointers, but with handle classes it does have references.

Separately, it's not possible in MATLAB to index in to the output of a function (i.e. to write `GetFoo.a` or `GetFoo().a` - you do need a temporary variable for that, whether or not it returns a value or handle class.

Note that in your example above, the result of the `GetFoo().a = 10` is not an instance of `foo` with the property `a` equal to 10 - it is a structure with a field `a` equal to 10. Type `class(GetFoo)`, and you'll see it's a struct, not a foo.

Answer (score 0):

This is really ugly, but is just to raise the glove that was thrown about doing it in one line. :-)

First of all, I'll modify a bit the class so you'll see that the constructor is called:

```
classdef foo
properties
        a = 0;
end;

methods
        function obj = foo()
                obj.a = 5;
                display('foo!');
        end;
end;
end
```

And the one-liner, ran in Command Window:

```
>> subsasgn(GetFoo(), struct('type', '.', 'subs', 'a'), 10);
foo!
```